# redefine C-x C-e to evaluate custom language expression

Tags: emacs, elisp

I've defined a major mode for my language.
I'm trying to redefine C-x C-e so that when I'm in my major mode, it'd evaluate the expression using "my" custom interpreter.

Suppose my interpreter is just a command-line program that could be invoked like this:

```
$my-interpreter <some expression>
```

I imagine, all I need to do is to do a system call, passing the expression "before point" as argument and print the return value in the echo area.
How hard could it be, right?

**Problem: I have no idea where to start!
Any hint?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at `shell-command` and its relatives, along with `thing-at-point`.  Here's a really simple example that uses an "interpreter" (just the shell `echo` command) to echo the word at point:

```
(defun my-interpreter ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((arg (thing-at-point 'word)))
    (when arg
      (shell-command (concat "echo " arg)))))
```

(Edit in response to comment.)
If you have defined a keymap for your major mode, you can bind `C-x C-e` in you major mode with a call to [`define-key`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Changing-Key-Bindings.html).  Otherwise, you can just bind it locally with `(local-set-key (kbd "C-x C-e") 'my-interpreter)`.

It occurred to me that you might be interested in building in interactive functionality like a REPL.  To do so, you might consider `comint-mode`; see the [EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ComintMode) and [this post from Mastering Emacs](http://www.masteringemacs.org/articles/2013/07/31/comint-writing-command-interpreter/) to get inspired.

Comment: Awesome! Does exactly what I need. Of course, I still need to find out how to bind that to `C-x C-e`. But thank you!!!

Comment: Edited answer now explains how to bind the command to a key combination.

Comment: Thanks, again! just made this "the answer". :)

Comment: I've got this error while executing the `local-key-set`:  /bin/bash: -c: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
/bin/bash: -c: line 1: `(local-set-key (kbd "C-x C-e") 'my-interpreter)''

Comment: I don't know much about bash scripting so can't be much help, but I'd make sure that what you're passing to the script as a string (via `thing-at-point` and the call to `concat`) is giving your script the expected syntax.